# Format DataPager Links

Tags: asp.net, datapager

Actually all I want is to add `#lastTab` at the end of the links rendered by DataPager control in Asp.NET.

Since I like the `NumericalField` such as "1 2 3..." I don't want to mess up with the default implementation.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I didn't want to resort to `jQuery and javascript` but they were the last chance.

Here is the code :

```
    $("#ctl00_HomeMasterContentPlaceHolder_printReviews_printReviewPager a").each(function (index, value) {
        if ($(this).attr("href") != "undefined")
            $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#last");
    });
```

They solved everything eventually.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987386/customize-asp-net-datapager-generated-html for another option.